# Dispose(); causing a null pointer exception error in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dispose

I have created a project with multiple GUI classes. Everything seems to be running fine, however when I try to implement the dispose(); function it provides the following error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JFrame.dispose()" because "Login.loginframe" is null
at Login.actionPerformed(Login.java:123)

Here is the following code:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Login loginframe = new Login();
    
    
    
    

}
```

}

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Login implements ActionListener {
private static JLabel userlabel , success , logo;
private static JTextField userText;
private static JLabel passwordlabel;
private static JPasswordField passwordtext;
private static JButton loginbutton , continuebutton;//, continuebutton2;
private static JFrame loginframe;
private static JPanel panel;




Login(){
    
    
    JFrame loginframe = new JFrame ("Login");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    loginframe.setSize(300, 300);
    loginframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loginframe.add(panel);
    loginframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    userlabel = new JLabel("User :");
    userlabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
    panel.add(userlabel);
    
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
    panel.add(userText);
    
    passwordlabel = new JLabel ("Password : ");
    passwordlabel.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
    panel.add(passwordlabel);
    
    passwordtext = new JPasswordField ();
    passwordtext.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
    panel.add(passwordtext);
    
    logo = new JLabel();
    logo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("emblem.jpg"));
    logo.setBounds(115, 90, 50, 50);
    panel.add(logo);
    
    
    loginbutton = new JButton("Submit");
    loginbutton.setBounds(100, 200, 80, 25);
    loginbutton.setEnabled(true);
    loginbutton.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(loginbutton);
    
    success = new JLabel("");
    success.setBounds(85, 130, 150, 80);
    panel.add(success);
    
    
    loginframe.setVisible(true);
    
    continuebutton = new JButton("Continue");
    continuebutton.setBounds(85, 200, 100, 25);
    continuebutton.addActionListener(this);
    continuebutton.setVisible(false);
    continuebutton.setEnabled(false);
    panel.add(continuebutton);
    

    
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    
    String user = userText.getText();
    String password = passwordtext.getText();
    System.out.println(user + ", " + password);
    
    
    if(user.equals("admin") && password.equals("password1")) {
        success.setText("Log in successful!");
        loginbutton.setVisible(false);
        loginbutton.setEnabled(false);
        continuebutton.setVisible(true);
        continuebutton.setEnabled(true);

        if(e.getSource()==continuebutton) {
            userText.setText("");
            passwordtext.setText("");
            new adminmain();
            loginframe.dispose();
            
    }
        }
    
    if(user.equals("user") && password.equals("password")) {
        success.setText("Log in successful!");
        loginbutton.setVisible(false);
        loginbutton.setEnabled(false);
        continuebutton.setVisible(true);
        continuebutton.setEnabled(true);

        if(e.getSource()==continuebutton) {
            userText.setText("");
            passwordtext.setText("");
            new usermain();
            loginframe.dispose();
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    }
```

}

Comment: You're shadowing your variables, `loginframe` is declared as both a local variable in the constructor and as an instance field.  Why you're at it, drop the use of `static`, it's not helping you and have a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as the `null` layout isn't helping your either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in your main method is your issue `JFrame loginframe = new JFrame ("Login");`

You are assigning the value of `loginframe` to a local variable within the main method, whereas the actionPerformed method is referring to the class variable `loginframe` at the top of your `Login` class.

By simply changing this line:

```
JFrame loginframe = new JFrame ("Login");
```

To be this, you will now be assigning the value to be a class variable and not run into null pointer issues:

```
loginframe = new JFrame ("Login");
```

Caution: Using a static variable like that is not a good idea if you will have multiple instances of the Login object/class.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run the code, it gives me this error. So, If I'm correct is adminmain() or usermain() are from different classes. If try importing the classes In to the main class. If you have found the solution please reply with the solution I can learn from it. Thanks.

```
Login.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    login();
    ^
```

symbol:   method login()
location: class Login
Login.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
new adminmain();
^
symbol:   class adminmain
location: class Login
Login.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
new usermain();
^
symbol:   class usermain
location: class Login
Login.java:142: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
return ex;
^
4 errors

Comment: The asker has not provided complete code so that error is to be expected. Remove the lines with adminmain and usermain then try run it again and you'll be able to diagnose the nullPointerException as explained in the above answer and comment.